# Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 5

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters, conversation

While reading a comic book, I have some problems with seeing some characters in this older copy of a book (the Chinese character is sometimes too dark to distinguish strokes and scanning doesn't help).

Here is the work that I have done so far. Thank you for any help finding the missing characters (I don't need the translations, per se but just seeing a clear copy of the character would be helpful).

There are multiple questions because I want to show the work in context. I could break these up into smaller questions but that would not be helpful to other learners (learning conversation) and would unnecessarily clog the website.

**Pane 1** ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 你是指我会（？）吊（？）来，和（？）火烤吗：

**Pane 2** ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 那些都小事一（？）：-> looks like 香 with a radical

**Pane 3** ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 我回（？）你到老（？）之（？）都不会（？）到大（？）折。：
>
> 什么！！：What!

**Pane 4** ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 你是說你能（？）知道一个人的命（？）：
>
> 沒错！：Yes!

**Pane 5** ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 你一定想問我为社么知道对不对？：You must know what to ask me for, right?
>
> 啊，对。。。：right...

[image: doraemon-1-5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Panel 1**

`你是指我會被吊起來，和被火烤嗎？`: "Are you saying I will be strung up and roasted with fire?"

Missing character: **`被`, `起`, `被`**

---

**Panel 2**

`這些都是小事一樁`: "Those are all no big deal."

Missing character: **`樁`**

---

**Panel 3**

`我會讓你到老死之前都不會遇到大波折`: "I'll make sure you meet no major set backs until you die of old age."

Missing character: **`讓`, `死`, `遇`, `波`**

Wrong character: **`回` -> `會|会`**

---

**Panel 4**

`你是說你能夠知道一個人的命運`： "Are you saying you can see someone's future?" (or more literally: "know a person's fate")

`沒錯`: "That's right!"

Missing character: **`夠`, `運`**

---

**Panel 5**

`你一定想問我為什麼知道對不對`: "You must be wondering why I know, right?" (or more literally, "wanting to ask")

`嗯， 對`: "Umm, yes."

Wrong character: **`啊` -> `嗯`**